# php get the number of a given instance in an array

Tags: php, count

Basically, I'm trying to make a table where the color slightly changes for each row.

I'm going to do this by naming each even row `class="even"` and every odd row `class="odd"`.

In my loop then, I need to figure out if the instance of the array is odd or even.

I can do **almost** do this by writing:

```
if (count($row)%2 == 0)  //while $row is an array from a mysql query
    {
    echo "<tr class='even'>";

if (count($row)%2 == 1)
    {
    echo "<tr class='odd'>";
    }
```

However writing `count($row)` gives me the count for the whole array, not the number of the instance which indicates where it falls in the whole array. Any ideas on how I could get the number of the instance within the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use PHP for this. Use CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: ... which still needs to be generated using PHP. Jeff's content is presumably not static, since he mentions a database query.

Comment: @Jared: His content can be dynamic, that doesn't mean he should use PHP for the style.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve his problem, which is a PHP one, not a CSS one. Besides, nobody said he wasn't using CSS.

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38 `nth-child` is unsupported in quite some browsers (especially IE).

Comment: @JRL this css features is very nice -- much simpler than stupid class names - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($row)) {
  if (($i % 2) == 0) {
    echo "<tr class='even'>";
  } else {
    echo "<tr class='odd'>";
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to increment `$i`.

Comment: @Jared Ng: Your edit will not produce what you expect. You should increment at the end of the while body.

Comment: This should have no problems. Sorry, it's been a while since I've touched PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a counter:

```
$i = 0   
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($yourquery)) {
   if ($i % 2 == 0) {
      echo "<tr class='even'>";
   } else {
      echo "<tr class='odd'>";
   } 
   $i++;   
}
```